# Finding solutions to the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I want to find possible solution satisfying both the equation:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i^{2} = n$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i=0$

As the number of equations less than number of variables can we just comment on some properties that solutions will have like the following below:

For example a possible solution to the above equation set can be(I got it by hit and trail and intuition)

$f_i$ =
   \begin{cases} 
      \sqrt{\frac{|\overline{A}|}{|A|}} & v_i \in A \\
      \sqrt{\frac{|A|}{|\overline{A}|}} & v_i \in \overline{A} \\
   \end{cases}

where $A$ is any set and $|A|=n$

Comment: The set of vectors of the form, $(f_1,...f_n)$ lives in an n dimensional vector space. You second equation describes a subspace of one dimension less while the first describes an n-1 dimensional sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$. Thus the intersection of the two is some n-2 dimensional sphere.

Comment: @BabyDragon Thanks. Can we formulate this mathematically, like some generalization?

Comment: That is quite a math formulation. It seems to me like [constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_optimization) in optimization. Those constraints draw a subdomain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which needs to be determined case by case, depending on the given constraints.